# Replacing query arg string from Wordpress Woocomerce Url

Tags: wordpress, string, url

I need your help with this customization of my wordpress woocomerce website. Please, I need to replace the querystring from this url (when products ordering):

http://example.com/tienda/producto/categoria/soluciones-para-oficina/?orderby=popularidad

to:

http://example.com/tienda/producto/categoria/soluciones-para-oficina/?ordenar-por=popularidad

Can you give some ideas? I try using add_query_arg but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why do you need this change? Orderby is a reserved word in WordPress and WooCommerce - it provides a function, and replacing it will change the functionality of the page.

Comment: I need to change this "orderby"  keyword because i will try to show a language friendly url.

Comment: I understand. However, from the documentation I read the URL is not just for the users/browser - it's includes reserved words for the WordPress engine to parse as well. I don't believe it can be replaced, sorry.